# SAP B1 Studio for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, sapb1

How do I install the SAP Business One Add-On Project templates for Visual Studio 2022?

I upgraded my VS from 2019 to 2022 and installed the latest SAP B1 Version 10 FP 2111. But the installer says it cannot find Visual Studio installed. How do I get to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess VS2022 is not yet supported from SAP.

Answer (score 0):

you should install sapb1 tools sdk vb again, then i think you will see the sapb1 addon project menu

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the SAP B1 SDK,

The SDK is included with any Business One patch or installer, in a subfolder called "Packages\SAP Business One SDK".

https://andresnaranjo.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/tb1300_en_col92.pdf